# Setting minimum height and width for a chrome window in firefox

Tags: firefox, window, size, limit

I'm trying to limit the minimum height and width of a chrome (xul) window. The window itself is opened using the ***window.openDialog*** method. I tried using the ***minwidth*** and ***minheight*** window propertiet, but that does not seem to have any effect on the window.
I also tries to limit the size by handling the ***onresize*** event as follows:

```
onresize()
{
  return false;
}
```

but this does not work as well.

Any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured out the answer.

There is no straightforward solution. It seems that for sub-windows, opened by an *open* or *opendialog* method,it is impossible to limit the minimum size using the standard properties, however by using a combination of the ***onresize*** event handler and the ***window.resizeTo()*** method, I could get the window to maintain a minimum size.

Comment: Seems like alot of effort for a somewhat edge-case problem.

Answer (score 0):

`onresize` isn't a function. To accomplish this, you will need to set the value TO a function. Just do something like this:

```js
onresize = (function() { return false; });
```